# C++ template class inherits from template class, cannot access member variable

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I try to make a class template where a parameterized class Child inherits from a parameterized class Base. The derived class cannot access the members in the base class though.

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
  T _value;
};

template <typename T>
class Child: Base<T>
{
public:
  T accessValue()
  {
    return _value;
  }
};
```

This gives the following error message:

> main.cpp: In member function 'T Child::accessValue()': main.cpp:21:
>   error: '_value' was not declared in this scope

It works if I change the declaration to:

```
template <typename T>
class Child: Base<int>
```

but that obviously defies the purpose of the whole template thing.

I Think this must be something really basic but I could not find a solution neither on this site nor anywhere else. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `this->_value` or `Base<T>::_value`